# RETS data fetching problem

Tags: rets

I am working on one real estate website which is Using RETS service to get the data to my local server.

but I have one little bit problem here,I can fetch data from RETS which is having about 3lacks record in RETS Database but I didn't find the way,How can I fetch that all records in bunch of 50k at a time ?

I didn't find any 'LIMIT' keyword on RETS.so how can I fetch without 'LIMIT' 50k records at a time?

Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RETS is not really much of a standard.  It's more closely resembles a pseudo standard.  It loosely defines an XML schema that describes real estate listings.

In version 1.x, the "standard" was composed of DTD documents.  In 2.x, the "standard" uses XSD documents to describe the list.

http://www.rets.org/documentation

However, in practice, there is almost no consistency amongst implementers.  Having connected to hundreds of "RETS Compliant" service providers, I'm convinced that not one of them is like any other one.

Furthermore, the 2.x "standard" has not changed in 3 years.  It's an unmaintained, sloppy attempt at a standard.  It (RETS) is often used as a business buzz word by non-technical people. In reality, it's just an arbitrary attempt at modeling real estate listing in XML.

Try asking the specific implementer for their documentation.  Often, they don't have any.  So, emailing the lead developer has frequently been helpful.  Sometimes they'll provide a WSDL which will outline the supported calls.  Often, the WSDL doesn't coincide with the actual service, so beware.

As for your specific question, try caching the results.  Usually, the use of a limit on a RETS call is a sign of a direct dependency.  As requests for your service increase, the load that your service puts on theirs will break (and not be appreciated).  Also, if their service goes down (even temporarily), yours will be interrupted as well.  Most importantly, it will make the live requests to your pages really, really slow (especially if their system is slow at the time).  The listings usually don't change frequently enough for worries about stale data, so caching up to and hour is pretty acceptable.

Best of luck!

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. RETS is a mess. Try to build an application that talks to more than 1 system and you're in for a massive headache.

Comment: I am attempting this now, I thought i was going to use PHP but now it seems that I should use RETS either. If I want to learn more about this where should I start? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you described your problem a little further.  Perhaps you could create a new question and link back from this comment.

Answer (score 0):

libRets provides support for generating a query with fetch limits:

http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/librets/documentation/api/classlibrets_1_1_search_request.html

But last I knew:  I remember the company Intereality either ignored or outright didn't provide complete compatibility to RETS.  Quickest way to know your dealing with them is that also thought making all "System" name's for table fields numeric.

If you're lucky, you're using a Rapattoni backed server and they do provide spec. compatible servers.

Last point, I can't for the life of me remember it's name, but I used to use a free Java based RETS tool to build valid queries ( included offset/limit clauses ) and that made it a tad easier to build automated fetchers for a client's batch processing system.

Comment: You're probably thinking of MRIS Conduit.

Answer (score -1):

IN RETS if Count More Than limit then We can download using Batch form or we can remove that Limit using regex while downloading

Best way to solve Problem divide Data Count in small unit of download and while we have to consider download limit in mind Field for Divide that one in MLS/IDX I Suggest Modification Date and ListingDate